# What does RSGD stand for?

Tags: gradient-descent

I'm reading a [paper](https://papers.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2019/hash/82c2559140b95ccda9c6ca4a8b981f1e-Abstract.html) that involves an algorithm for RSGD. It's clearly a form of stochastic gradient descent, but I can't find what the R stands for. The authors provide their own implementation of it, and I would like to find its original formulation to compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably Riemannian stochastic gradient descent (R-SGD), (Stochastic Gradient Descent on Riemannian Manifolds).

You'll find several articles on the subject by searching for this term.